# Hadoop Image Processing Interface

Tags: hadoop

I have one question about HIPI as I new in these field..I am trying to run simple example and my command is like.:

```
$> bin/hadoop jar /opt/hipi-dev/examples/downloader.jar /user/hduser/hipiFile /user/hduser/outputhipi.hib 1
```

Where hipiFile folder contain one text file containing 4 image url. Path in my build.xml file is right. Though it gives me following error:

```
14/03/09 09:44:01 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
Found host successfully: 0
Tried to get 1 nodes, got 1
14/03/09 09:44:01 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
First n-1 nodes responsible for 4 images
Last node responsible for 4 images
14/03/09 09:44:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201403090903_0003
14/03/09 09:44:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/09 09:44:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201403090903_0003_m_000000_0,    
**Status : FAILED**

**Error:** java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at hipi.examples.downloader.Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Unknown Source)
    at hipi.examples.downloader.Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether hadoop-common-*.jar's are in class path.